# LINQ to SQL - Checking the field length

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting rows from Access DB. I need to check certain fields for length. I got that to work, but the problem is if the field comes as a NULL. Then my check fails.
This is how I initially made it to check for length (array[0] is a column name to be checked), and it works:

```
results = query.Where(p => p.Field<string>(array[0]).Length > 10);
```

Now the problem is if the field is NULL. Screen shot displays the field that is coming as empty and it fails my check. Field number is 25.

How can I make it to ignore nulls and still check for length?
[image]

Comment: Why don't you add a check for NULL then ... ?

Comment: I totally forgot about it :(

Comment: If you are on C#6 (VS2015), just put `?` before `.Length`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this to avoid nulls.

```
results = query.Where(p => 
    !String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Field<string>(array[0])) 
    &&  p.Field<string>(array[0]).Length > 10);
```

Comment: When using LINQ-to-SQL and an SQL Server db (different than the OP's scenario), IsNullOrEmpty() causes `Method 'Boolean IsNullOrEmpty(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.`, so a standard null check is needed instead.