# order by len() but in linq with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

this is my query in sql server and everything works fine

```
select * from DetalleNotas
order by len(ColProduct), ColProduct

PROCT1
PROCT2
PROCT3
PROCT4
PROCT5
PROCT6
PROCT7
PROCT8
PROCT9
PROCT10
```

but i want my query in linq c#

***I tried this and it does not work***

```
var product = (from d in db.Product
                orderby len(d.ColProduct), d.ColProduct
                select new
                {
                    product= d.product
                });
```

[image] *the name "len" does not exist in the real context*

***only this query works***

```
var product = (from d in db.DetalleNotas
                orderby d.ColProduct
                select new
                {
                    product= d.product
                });
```

***This is the result of my functional query***

```
PROCT1
PROCT10
PROCT2
PROCT3
PROCT4
PROCT5
PROCT6
PROCT7
PROCT8
PROCT9
```

Comment: *"does not work"* in what way does it not work? Do you see errors?

Comment: mi error is **the name "len" does not exist in the real context**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to SQL - Checking the field length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35225816/linq-to-sql-checking-the-field-length)

Comment: You need ColProduct.Length instead of len

Comment: @Seano666 not, mi question is deferent,

Comment: note that this will completely destroy index usage for that query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that in C# Linq code, everything is still C#. As you're working with strings you need to order by [`string.Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). For example:

```
var results = from d in db.DetalleNotas
              orderby d.ColProduct.Length
              select d;
```

Answer (score 5):

You could order it by the number on the end of your strings:

```
var result = db.DetalleNotas.OrderBy(d => Convert.ToInt32(d.ColProduct.Substring(5)))
                            .ToArray();
```